# Is there a way to decode numerical COM error-codes in pywin32

Tags: python, windows, excel, com, pywin32

Here is part of a stack-trace from a recent run of an unreliable application written in Python which controls another application written in Excel:

```
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2146788248), None)
```

Obviously something has gone wrong ... but what?[1] These COM error codes seem to be excessively cryptic.

How can I decode this error message? Is there a table somewhere that allows me to convert this numerical error code into something more meaningful?

[1] I actually know what went wrong in this case, it was attempting to access a Name prperty on a Range object which did not have a Name property... not all bugs are this easy to find!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong. The first item in your stack trace (the number) is the error code returned by the COM object. The second item is the description associated with the error code which in this case is "Exception Occurred". pywintypes.com_error already called the equivalent of win32api.FormatMessage(errCode) for you. We'll look at the second number in a minute.

*By the way, you can use the "Error Lookup" utility that comes in Visual Studio (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Tools\ErrLook.exe) as a quick launching pad to check COM error codes. That utility also calls FormatMessage for you and displays the result. Not all error codes will work with this mechanism, but many will. That's usually my first stop.*

Error handling and reporting in COM is a bit messy. I'll try to give you some background.

All COM method calls will return a numeric code called an HRESULT that can indicate success or failure. All forms of error reporting in COM build on top of that.

The codes are commonly expressed in hex, although sometimes you will see them as large 32-bit numbers, like in your stack trace. There are all kinds of predefined return codes for common results and problems, or the object can return custom numeric codes for special situations. For example, the value 0 (called S_OK) universally means "No error" and 0x80000002 is E_OUTOFMEMORY. Sometimes the HRESULT codes are returned by the object, sometimes by the COM infrastructure.

A COM object can also choose to provide much richer error information by implementing an interface called IErrorInfo. When an object implements IErrorInfo, it can provide all kinds of detail about what happened, such as a detailed custom error message and even the name of a help file that describes the problem. In VB6 and VBA. the `Err` object allows you to access all that information (`Err.Description`, etc).

To complicate matters, late bound COM objects (which use a mechanism called COM Automation or IDispatch) add some layers that need to be peeled off to get information out. Excel is usually manipulated via late binding.

Now let's look at your situation again. What you are getting as the first number is a fairly generic error code: DISP_E_EXCEPTION. *Note: you can usually figure out the official name of an HRESULT by googling the number, although sometimes you will have to use the hex version to find anything useful.*

Errors that begin with DISP_ are IDISPATCH error codes. The error loosely means "There was a COM exception thrown by the object", with more information packed elsewhere (although I don't quite know where; I'll have to look it up).

From what I understand of pywintypes.com_error, the last number in your message is the actual error code that was returned by the object during the exception. It's the actual numeric code that you would get out of VBA's `Err.Number`.

Unfortunately, that second code -2146788248 (0x800A9C68) is in the range reserved for custom application-defined error messages (in VBA: `VbObjectError + someCustomErrorNumber`), so there is no centralized meaning. The same number can mean entirely different things for different programs.

In this case, we have reached a dead end:

> The error code is "custom", and the application needs to document what it is, except that Excel doesn't. Also, Excel (or the actual source of the error) doesn't seem to be providing any more information via IErrorInfo.

Excel is notorious (to me at least) for cryptic error codes from automation and obscure situations that cause them. This is especially so for errors that one could consider "design-time errors" ("you should have known better than calling a method that doesn't exist in the object"). Instead of a nice "Could not read the Name property", you get "***Run-time error '1004': Application defined or object-defined error***" (which I just got by trying to access a Name property on a Range, from VBA in Excel). That is NOT very helpful.

The problem is not routed on Python or it's interface to Excel. Excel itself doesn't explain what happened, even to VBA.

However, the general procedure above remains valid. If you get an error from Excel in the future, you might get a better error message that you can track the same way.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much! For anyone who's coming here with Visual Studio 10.0+, you can download the Error Lookup from the :https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=100432. Then use a terminal (cmd / powershell) to execute. You can search the error code as such "./Err_<version>.exe /winerror.h -21473525627" and that will return the error.

Answer (score 11):

Do it like this:

```
try:
    [whatever code]
except pythoncom.com_error as error:
    print(win32api.FormatMessage(error.excepinfo[5]))
```

More information on digesting the pythoncom.com_error object here: https://web.archive.org/web/20170831073447/http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/3.2/pywin32/com_error.html

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: Fixed link via wayback machine

Answer (score 7):

Yes try the win32api module:

```
import win32api
e_msg = win32api.FormatMessage(-2147352567)
```

You can grab any codes returned from the exception and pass them to FormatMessage. Your example had 2 error codes.

Comment: The first message was "Exception Occurred" and the 2nd one raised an error: The system cannot find message text for message number 0x%1 in the message file for %2.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 7):

Specifically for pythoncom, the errors codes that result are more than cryptic. This is because pythoncom represents them internally as a 32bit signed integer, when the correct representation is a 32bit *unsigned* integer. As a result, the conversion that you end up seeing in the stack trace is incorrect.

In particular, your exception, according to pythoncom, is -2147352567, and your (for lack of a better word) Err.Number is -2146788248.

This however causes some issues when watching for specific errors, like below:

```
DISP_E_EXCEPTION = 0x80020009
#...
#except pywintypes.com_error as e:
#    print repr(e)
#    #pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2146788248), None)
#    hr = e.hresult

hr = -2147352567
if hr == DISP_E_EXCEPTION:
    pass #This never occurs
else:
    raise
```

To see why this has issues, lets look into these error codes:

```
>>> DISP_E_EXCEPTION = 0x80020009
>>> DISP_E_EXCEPTION
2147614729L
>>> my_hr = -2147352567
>>> my_hr == DISP_E_EXCEPTION
False
```

Again, this is because python sees the constant declared as positive, and pythoncom's incorrect declaration interpreted it as negative. Of course, the most obvious solution fails:

```
>>> hex(my_hr)
'-0x7ffdfff7'
```

The solution is to properly interpret the number. Luckily, pythoncom's representation is reversible. We need to interpret the negative number as a 32 bit signed integer, then interpret *that* as an unsigned integer:

```
def fix_com_hresult(hr):
    import struct
    return struct.unpack("L", struct.pack("l", hr))[0]

>>> DISP_E_EXCEPTION = 0x80020009
>>> my_hr = -2147352567
>>> my_hr == DISP_E_EXCEPTION
False
>>> fixed_hr = fix_com_hresult(my_hr)
>>> fixed_hr
2147614729L
>>> fixed_hr == DISP_E_EXCEPTION
True
```

So, putting it all together, you need to run fix_com_hresult() on that result from pythoncom, essentially all the time.

Since normally you need to do this when checking for exceptions, I created these functions:

```
def fix_com_exception(e):
    e.hresult = fix_com_hresult(e.hresult)
    e.args = [e.hresult] + list(e.args[1:])
    return e

def fix_com_hresult(hr):
    import struct
    return struct.unpack("L", struct.pack("l", hr))[0]
```

which can then be used how you expect:

```
DISP_E_EXCEPTION = 0x80020009
try:
    #failing call
except pywintypes.com_error as e:
    print repr(e)
    #pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2146788248), None)
    fix_com_exception(e)
    print repr(e)
    #pywintypes.com_error: (2147614729L, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2146788248), None)
    if e.hresult == DISP_E_EXCEPTION:
        print "Got expected failure"
    else:
        raise
```

I was unable to find a MSDN document listing all HRESULTs, but I found this: http://www.megos.ch/support/doserrors_e.txt

Also, since you have it, fix_com_hresult() should also be run on your extended error code (-2146788248), but as Euro Micelli said, it doesn't help you in this particular instance :)

Answer (score 1):

No-one has yet mentioned the `strerror` attribute of the [`pywintypes.com_error` Exception](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/com_error.html). This returns the result of `FormatMessage` for the error code. So instead of doing it yourself like this

```
try:
    [whatever code]
except pythoncom.com_error as error:
    print(win32api.FormatMessage(error.excepinfo[5]))
```

You can just do this:

```
try:
    [whatever code]
except pythoncom.com_error as error:
    print(error.strerror)
```

Note it will return `None` if you have a non-standard `HRESULT` :(

Comment: `error.strerror` only returns the string of the first code, -2147352567, which is already in the question.