# Excel RTD server in Python not updating data

Tags: python, excel, com, rtd

I've got the [excelRTDserver.py](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~gfrancis/illimath/windows/aszgard_mini/movpy-2.0.0-py2.4.4/movpy/lib/win32com/demos/excelRTDServer.py) up and running in Excel 2010 (32bit) by changing the `EXCEL_TLB_MINOR` value to `7`. I can see the server in the add-ins list and if I enter `=RTD("Python.RTD.TimeServer","","seconds","5")` into a cell, I get the current time. But it never updates. If I change the "5" to another number, I get an update but after the initial change it never changes again.

How do I get it to update? I found someone else with a similar problem [here](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/2011-March/011324.html), but no solution.

UPDATE: I've got a little further - there is an exception raised within ServerStart when casting the PyIDispatch callback object into a IRTDUpdateEvent callback object. Using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5326994/597091) to capture the error message, I get "Cannot create a file when that file already exists.". If I follow the suggestion [here](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/2011-May/011499.html) and use `win32com.client.CastTo(CallbackObject,'IRTDUpdateEvent')` I get "This COM object can not automate the makepy process - please run makepy manually for this object", but I have already run makepy for Microsoft Excel 12.0 Object Library (1.6).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may be out of luck.

[According to the author of excelRTDServer.py in a recent python-win32 thread](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/2012-April/012207.html):

<sup>The message that this is in response to describes your *exact* problem, and it's recent, so maybe you already got this info directly, but in case you didn't...</sup>

> I fear that things with IRTDUpdateEvent have changed with recent versions
>   of excel (since Excel 2007? I guess that's not so 'recent' anymore...).
>
> While hunting around for news of interface changes, I came across this
>   thread in a java forum:
>
> http://www.nevaobject.com/phpbb3/viewtopic.php?t=516
>
> The part that worries me is this comment:
>
> > "Apparently in Excel 12 (Excel 2007) the RTD callback object that
> >     implements dual IRTDUpdateEvent interface throws exception (generic COM
> >     exception 0x80020009) when is called via IDispatch. If you use v-table
> >     binding the call to UpdateNotify succeeds. I don't really know whether it
> >     is a bug in Excel 12 or a feature."
>
> So far I haven't been able to confirm this against the MSDN information...
>   But if this is true, it does explain the problem being seen.  Many older
>   examples on the web, and pywin32+makepy treat this interface as IDispatch,
>   and wrap it accordingly.
>
> I don't think we can fix this with pywin32 as it is right now. My
>   understanding is that it relies on IDispatch support. May need to look at
>   comtypes (http://starship.python.net/crew/theller/comtypes/) to wrap the
>   (new?) IRTDUpdateEvent objects, or maybe a C extension. :(

Comment: Yeah, I posted the question there as well. It does look like I'm out of luck.

Answer (score 4):

To work around this problem I've created a new project on github for pythoncom excel types:

https://github.com/pyxll/exceltypes

This includes a slightly modified version of `excelRTDServer.py` that uses the new type `PyIRTDUpdateEvent` instead of the `win32com` makepy wrapper, and so it now works in Excel 2010 (look for the comments `'EXCELTYPES_MODIFICATION'` in `exceltypes/demos/excelRTDServer.py`).

To build the project you will need visual studio installed (it won't build with gcc) and you can build it using the setup.py included in the project as follows:

```
python setup.py install
```

If you need to force it to use visual studio instead of gcc use the `"--compiler=msvc"` option, if you're using anaconda for example.
If you want to use Visual Studio 2012 instead of the default 2010 add the following lines to `setup.py`:

```
from distutils import msvc9compiler
msvc9compiler.VERSION = 11
```

Answer (score 1):

**Python:**

*I get "This COM object can not automate the makepy process - please run makepy manually for this object", but I have already run makepy for Microsoft Excel 12.0 Object Library (1.6).*

Yesterday at work after a while reading your question, I forgot that is python and not java :)).. Well, the only thing I think now is that seems you need to run the [PIA](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/confirmation.aspx?id=3508) for office 2010.

Edit later: if you steel have problems after what i told you., please comment and not downvote, because this issue is uncommon.

**JAVA:**

This happen because is missing the option to generate **v-tables**.

You need to modify *ServerStart* method and also `IRTDServer` interface and `IRTDServer_Impl class`., so `CallbackObject` is `COMIUnknown`. Then you need to generate `IRTDServer_Skel` class by runing the *IBuilder*.

Now you can generate a new java wrapper for *`IRTDUpdateEvent`* to request v-table:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response, it is appreciated. However, I'm looking for a Python solution. Sadly I'm not fluent in Java.

Comment: The downvote was not me, I'm asking for help and you're giving it. Unfortunately, I installed the PIA but it didn't help.

Comment: pff., tomorrow i check it, 0:30a.m here

Answer (score 0):

That error message sometimes is raised when u put it in something like 'for'-loop,here is a hackly solution 4u:import time,and use  'sleep()' in your loop

Answer (score -1):

The `IRTDUpdateEvent` problem (throwing exception) as described in [here](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/2011-March/011324.html) should be fixed in the latest Office 365 version.

> "Apparently in Excel 12 (Excel 2007) the RTD callback object that implements dual IRTDUpdateEvent interface throws exception (generic COM exception 0x80020009) when is called via IDispatch. If you use v-table binding the call to UpdateNotify succeeds. I don't really know whether it is a bug in Excel 12 or a feature."

Therefore [excelRTDserver.py](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~gfrancis/illimath/windows/aszgard_mini/movpy-2.0.0-py2.4.4/movpy/lib/win32com/demos/excelRTDServer.py) should work fine with the latest version of Office. In other words, `=RTD("Python.RTD.TimeServer","","seconds","5")` should continuously get updated as expected.