# Little to big endian buffer at once python

Tags: python, endianness

I've created a buffer of words represented in little endian(Assuming each word is 2 bytes):

```
A000B000FF0A
```

I've separated the buffer to 3 words(2 bytes each)

```
A000
B000
FF0A
```

and after that converted to big endian representation:

```
00A0
00B0
0AFF
```

Is there a way instead of split into words to represent the buffer in big endian at once?
Code:

```
buffer='A000B000FF0A'
for i in range(0, len(buffer), 4):
    value = endian(int(buffer[i:i + 4], 16))

def endian(num):
    p = '{{:0{}X}}'.format(4)
    hex = p.format(num)
    bin = bytearray.fromhex(hex).reverse()
    l = ''.join(format(x, '02x') for x in bin)
    return int(l, 16)
```

Comment: Which datatype are you using to represent these words?

Comment: @Fra93 those words are unsigned int.

Comment: I am not sure I have understood your question. Python does not have natively an unsigned int. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20766813/how-to-convert-signed-to-unsigned-integer-in-python#:~:text=on%20this%20post.-,Python%20doesn't%20have%20builtin%20unsigned%20types.,fixed%2Dbyte%2Dsize%20integer.

Comment: Can you show us the code you wrote to achieve the results you have in your post?

Comment: @Fra93 I've added the code. buffer is string

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to do, but Numpy can do that sort of thing easily and fast https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.byteswapping.html Or you could look at `struct.unpack()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) or [array](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) libraries are probably the easiest ways to do this.

Converting the [hex string to bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.fromhex) first is needed.

Here is an example of how it could be done:

```py
from array import array
import struct

hex_str = 'A000B000FF0A'
raw_data = bytes.fromhex(hex_str)
print("orig string:      ", hex_str.casefold())
# With array lib
arr = array('h')
arr.frombytes(raw_data)
# arr = array('h', [160, 176, 2815])
arr.byteswap()
array_str = arr.tobytes().hex()
print(f"Swap using array: ", array_str)

# With struct lib
arr2 = [x[0] for x in struct.iter_unpack('<h', raw_data)]
# arr2 = [160, 176, 2815]
struct_str = struct.pack(f'>{len(arr2) * "h"}', *arr2).hex()
print("Swap using struct:", struct_str)
```

Gives transcript:

```bash
orig string:       a000b000ff0a
Swap using array:  00a000b00aff
Swap using struct: 00a000b00aff
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the struct to interpret your bytes as big or little endian. Then you can use the `hex()` method of the bytearray object to have a nice string representation.

[Docs for struct.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html)

```
import struct

# little endian
a = struct.pack("<HHH",0xA000,0xB000,0xFF0A) 

# bih endian
b = struct.pack(">HHH",0xA000,0xB000,0xFF0A) 

print(a)
print(b)

# convert back to string
print( a.hex()  )
print( b.hex() )
```

Which gives:

```
b'\x00\xa0\x00\xb0\n\xff'
b'\xa0\x00\xb0\x00\xff\n'
00a000b00aff
a000b000ff0a
```