# Converting decimal to hex signed 2's complement

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, hex

I need to convert ID's into hex signed 2's complement.

A sample of the data frame:

| osiId |
| --- |
| -3839344128100363916 |
| 3706509458083282923 |
| -6999440164179221150 |
| -8641005918235945332 |
| -2906403792682509248 |
| 1747872771634044177 |

Tried this but it only works for positive numbers:

`df1['osiId'] = df1['osiId'].apply(hex)`

Thank you.

Comment: the `apply()`  method lets you apply a function.  do you have a function called `hex` ?

Comment: hex is a built-in python function

Comment: in that respect, you are asking to convert signed-unsigned integers, so this is your answer  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20766813/how-to-convert-signed-to-unsigned-integer-in-python